# Second iteration of a challenge

Tags: discussion, duplicates, challenges

I wrote [a challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/126063/macgyvers-toolbox), I was [concerned it would need some fine tuning](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12825/test-a-question), but was not able to get anyone on board to help me test.  So I posted it to the main and it turned out while it was pretty fun it did need a good deal of tuning.

I would like to do a improved version of the challenge.  I don't want to modify the old challenge because there are already *over 50 answers* on it and a rule change midway through would not be fair to the players.  However the new challenge wouldn't be much different, I would tweak the scoring system and change a couple of numbers in the challenge to make things a bit more difficult along with implementing a number of user suggestions.  It would definitely be solidly in dupe territory.  So what can I do?  Should we make an exception? Should we close the older question as a dupe of the newer one? (I've never seen that done on this site but it does happen on other sites)

Comment: If you decide to post the second iteration, regardless of what is done with the first iteration, you should wait for a while before actually posting it. If you post it in a month or two, after the original has died down, you could make a stronger case for it being different enough to not be a dupe, since it wouldn't be drawing attention away from the original.

Comment: @Mego I would have thought it best to post the challenge as soon as possible, that way the idea is still pretty fresh and people are interested.  I feel people are probably more likely to VTC when they don't think a challenge is interesting.  Although perhaps in a month people will have largely forgotten about the old one and the idea will be fresh again.

Comment: We could close the first as a dupe of the second...?

Comment: @WheatWizard That's kind of what I was thinking - in a month, the challenge will have died down, and so the second iteration will be fresh. It's especially a good idea if the old one will be closed as a dupe of the new one, because you don't want to close a good challenge while it is still getting answers.

Comment: @Mego Ok I see I get what you are saying. But I wouldn't call the old one a "good challenge" ;)

Comment: Definitely agree on closing the first as a dupe of the second. Call it a beta run. If someone *~in the future~* discovers the old one they would be directed to the new one, which would have a better algorithm. I certainly thought the original was intriguing, but definitely had some trouble spots (there were no less than five instances where the entire alphabet was available, despite previous answers--like TRANSCRIPT--having "used up" lots of them, which may have been fine, but I feel it detracted from the "restricted source" flag).