# How do I deal with lack of attention in the Sandbox?

Tags: support, sandbox

I know there are a lot of questions like this, but I didn't find any answer that satisfied me.

I'm pretty new to PPCG, so not all of my ideas are fantastic (e.g., this [failure](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170449/goldbachs-comet) of a challenge) but I like proposing a lot of question concepts.

However, part of the reason my last question (tagged above) was such a disappointment was the lack of feedback I received on my Sandbox post. Sure, I might have rushed posting the challenge out of excitement, but now I'm worried that my newest challenge doesn't end up in the same place this last one did.

So I have to ask: what's the best policy to deal with lack of attention on your challenge in the Sandbox. Should I just wait until someone responds? Or should I just try my luck in the main exchange? Or some combination of the above.

Sorry for the really bad question. I'll make sure to try to follow PPCG rules better in the future.

I should also note that I have read the question that discusses the issue of receiving few comments on posts, but I'm more concerned that the lack of comments is due to the difficulty of the challenges, rather than how great they are.

Comment: I feel you: questions that are difficult to understand (or require a decent baseline in math/etc) receive even *less* feedback.  But if you aren't getting feedback, absolutely bring it up in chat.

Comment: Lack of people reviewing the sandbox is a known problem. https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12599/we-need-to-talk-about-the-sandbox Another problem is that some problem can only be found while solving the challenge.

Comment: Lack of responses in the Sandbox can indeed be annoying. Here some tips however to improve it at least slightly: 1. Add explicit questions for the Sandbox in your proposed challenge. I.e. "Is anything unclear?'; "Should I add more rules?"; "Are the tags ok?"; etc. That way people might answer those questions, and a discussion/other questions might follow. 2. If no response was given after 24/48 hours, use the [The Ninetheeth Byte chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) to ask for attention.

Comment: If still no one responses, and you think everything is clear and are happy with the challenge, post it after at least 72 hours to main anyway stating it has been in the Sandbox for 72 hours in a comment (with a link to the now deleted Sandbox post). That way people can't complain if the challenge still lacks something. Even after the Sandbox, other remarks/edge cases/lack of certain rules are almost always found after a challenge is posted to main after people actually start doing the challenge. But if it's at least perfected somewhat in the Sandbox it's better than putting it in main directly

Comment: If I'm reading the timestamps right, it looks like the challenge was posted to the main site *3 minutes* after it was posted to the Sandbox. Is that correct?

Comment: @sundar well, I had accidently posted in both places, but then deleted the main post for about 24 hours, before bringing it back.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback!

Comment: [Related/Dupe?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13291/31625)

Comment: Most of these comments should be answers, not comments.

Comment: @3D1T0R I do agree! Some shameless self promotion, please do review my new KOTH in the Sandbox! Need help getting it into shape/